# How do I get Hadoop / Spark running on Windows? I need to run an IDE, do unit testing, set breakpoints - running under Docker container will not do

Tags: windows, hadoop, spark

How do I get Hadoop to run on Windows 10 Pro x64 (AMD)?

Every stackoverflow article, and even the documentation at Hadoop is years old and out of date, and does not work, something has changed and the documentation is out of sync - very badly so.

I created a windows env var HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop and put hadoop.dll and winutils.exe in %HADOOP_HOME%\bin, and still nothing works.

I added %HADOOP_HOME%\bin to PATH

Is there anyone that has done this within the last month, and can please share the steps you took?

Pointing me to any documentation that can be found with a search engine search, or search in stackoverflow has already been attempted.

Comment: Windows 10??????????

Comment: FYI HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop\ should be e.g. HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop (no trailing slash).

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 Pro x64 AMD.  

Also HADOOP_HOME is correctly set to:   C:\hadoop  (no trailing slash),

and also %HADOOP_HOME%\bin in in my PATH.  The above were not the issues, if you please have anything else to add.

One issue that would help would be to find pre-compiled binaries of hadoop.dll and winutils.exe for Windows 10 Pro x64 (they are not out there to be found anywhere)

There is no way to compile these, if you think it is possible, find the instructions and do it - you will see.

Comment: These do not work on Windows 10 Pro x64.  

https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin/winutils.exe
https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin/hadoop.dll

When running I get:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher